# How to restore firefox tabs from a bunch of blank 'New Tab'

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs

Ordinarily, Firefox will load all tabs from the past.

But now for some reason all of my Firefox tabs don't load. They're all blank 'New Tab'.

[image]

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, this can happen when Firefox has been loaded while the internet's been out. At the individual tab level, you may find that trying to refresh/stop a page just after Firefox has started may result in it completely forgetting what it was trying to load.

In addition, your Firefox tab UI looks very non-standard (are you using a tab-manager addon that could be causing bugs?), or you're using an old version of Firefox.